# bash: create a variable name containing another variable

Tags: bash, variables, naming-conventions

I have to create multiple variable while reading the file in bash.
These variables need to have a dynamic name as per the content of file.
E.g:

File content:

```
abc: 20
1 apple a day
abc: 40
1 keeps the doctor away
```

now i have to create variables as:

```
day_20_id = 1
day_20_fruit = apple
away_40_id = 1
away_40_who = doctor
```

it would be like in all variable names, only the the value of `$abc` will be updated and the value of the variable will be as per the file content.

Can somebody help me out to figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Why not use an array instead of multiple variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the eval command to accomplish this as illustrated below

```
abc=20  # assuming you got this from the input file
val=1   # assuming you also got this from the input file

varName="day_${abc}_id"
command="${varName}=${val}"
eval $command

# now print to output file as you have stated in the comments
outputFile=output.txt  # randomly-chosen name
command="echo $varName = $val > $outputFile"
eval $command
```

Comment: but if i'm echoing $day_20_id then that is making the code static. I need to echo $day_abc_id

Comment: The last line `echo $day_20_id` is just there to illustrate the effect of the eval.  It shows that a dynamically-named variable has been created.

Comment: Your "question" is _create a variable name containing another variable_.  that is what the above code snippet does.  What else are you asking for?

Comment: I need to print variable name along with its value in another file.

Comment: OK, answer is updated with exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yes this worked but its taking lot of variables. I'm modifying the solution. Thanks for your time and solution.